# Convert Map[String, Any] to nested case class with controlled Type casting

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I'd like to convert a Map[String, Any] to a given case class, and the map can be a nested map.
The case class can have certain fields as Optional, and if the map doesn't have the field in question , it'll have a default value.
eg.

```
case class CC(a: Int, b: Option[Int], c: String)
Map(a -> 1, c -> "abc")
result case class : CC(1, None, "abc")
```

The only caveat is I need to control the typeSignatures of these fields.
ex:

```
Map(a ->, b -> "10", c ->"abc"). \\Note b is string here
result case class : CC(1, Some(10), "abc")
```

I got some code that can do this exact behavior(code below), but I cant seem to make it work for nested case class

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._


object DynamicClassFactory {
  val classLoaderMirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
}

class DynamicClassFactory[T: TypeTag] {
    import DynamicClassFactory.classLoaderMirror

    val tpe = typeOf[T]
    val classSymbol = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
    val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companion
 

    val classMirror = classLoaderMirror reflectClass classSymbol
    val instanceMirror = classLoaderMirror.reflectModule(companion.asModule)
    val objMirror = classLoaderMirror.reflect(instanceMirror.instance)
    val constructorSymbol = tpe.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)
    val constructorArgs = constructorSymbol.asMethod.paramLists.flatten.map{
            p => (p.name.decodedName.toString, p.typeSignature)
          }
    val defaultConstructor =
      if (constructorSymbol.isMethod) constructorSymbol.asMethod
      else {
        val ctors = constructorSymbol.asTerm.alternatives
        ctors.map { _.asMethod }.find { _.isPrimaryConstructor }.get
      }

    val constructorMethod = classMirror reflectConstructor defaultConstructor
    
    def buildParameters: List[String] = constructorArgs.map ( x => x._1 )
    
    def getCompanionParam(name: String): Any = 
      if(classSymbol.isCaseClass) {
        objMirror.reflectMethod(instanceMirror.symbol.info.decl(TermName(name)).asMethod)("test")   
    }

    
    def getDefaults = {
      val defaults = companion.typeSignature.members.filter { m => m.isMethod && m.name.toString.contains("apply$default")}.toList.map { x => (x.asMethod.name.toTermName.toString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").toInt-1, getCompanionParam(x.asMethod.name.toTermName.toString)) }.toMap
      val defaultValues = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any]()
      for( (x, i) <- buildParameters.view.zipWithIndex ) {
        if(defaults.contains(i)) {
          defaultValues(x) = defaults(i)
        }
      }
      defaultValues.toMap
    }

    def buildWith(args: Seq[_]): T = {
      constructorMethod(args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
    }

    def buildSafe(configuration: Map[String, Any]): T = {
        val config = getDefaults ++ configuration
        val safeConfig = safeTypeConvert(config, constructorArgs.toMap)
        buildWith(constructorArgs.map { x => safeConfig(x._1) })
  }

  def safeTypeConvert(v: Map[String, Any], t: Map[String, Type]): Map[String, Any] = {
    val o = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any]()

    val z = v.filter{
      case (k, v) =>
        t.contains(k)
    }
    z.foreach {
      case (k, v) =>
        val typeS: Type = t(k)
        try {
          if (typeS <:< typeOf[Option[String]]) {
            v match {
              case x: Int => o(k) = Some(x.toString)
              case y: Option[Nothing] => o(k) = None
              case _ => o(k) = Some(v.asInstanceOf[String])
            }
          }
          else if (typeS <:< typeOf[Option[Int]]) {
            v match {
              case x: String => o(k) = Some(x.toFloat.toInt)
              case y: Option[Nothing] => o(k) = None
              case _ => o(k) = Some(v.asInstanceOf[Int])
            }
          }
          else if (typeS <:< typeOf[Option[Boolean]]) {
            v match {
              case x: String => o(k) = Some(x.toLowerCase.toBoolean)
              case y: Option[Nothing] => o(k) = None
              case _ => o(k) = v
            }
          }
          
          else if (typeS <:< typeOf[Int]) {
            v match {
              case x: String => o(k) = x.toFloat.toInt // this is to handle decimals returned from json
              case _ => o(k) = v.asInstanceOf[Int]
            }
          } else if (typeS =:= typeOf[String]) {
            v match {
              case x: Int => o(k) = x.toString
              case _ => o(k) = v.asInstanceOf[String]
            }
          } else if (typeS =:= typeOf[Boolean]) {
            v match {
              case x: String => o(k) = x.toLowerCase.toBoolean
              case _ => o(k) = v
            }
          }
          else if (typeS <:< typeOf[List[_]]) {
            if (v == Nil) {
              o(k) = List[String]()
            } else {
              o(k) = v.asInstanceOf[List[_]]
            }
          } else if (typeS <:< typeOf[Map[_, _]]) {
            if (v == None) {
              o(k) = Map()
            } else o(k) = v
          }
          else {
            throw new Exception(s"sdf $k must be of type ${typeS.typeSymbol.name.decoded}, got ${v.getClass.getName}: ${v.toString}")
          }
        } catch {
          case e@(_: ClassCastException | _: NumberFormatException | _: IllegalArgumentException) =>
            throw new Exception(s"$k must be of type ${typeS.typeSymbol.name.decoded}, got ${v.getClass.getName}: ${v.toString}")
        }
    }
    return o.toMap
  }
}
```

The above works great for a map which is not a nested map, but fails for a nested map

```
case class Address(addLine1: String, addLine2: Optional[String], zip: Long)
case class Inner(id: Option[String], addr: Option[Address], isPath: Option[Boolean])
case class Outer(name: String, addtlnInfo: Inner)

val map: Map[String, Any] = Map("name" -> "john", "addtlnInfo" -> Map("id" -> 123, "addr" -> Map("addLine1" -> "901 Lincoln St", "zip" -> "80101")))

val ins = new DynamicClassFactory[Outer]
ins.buildSafe(map)
```

Comment: Why do you have such **Map** in the first place? From where is it coming from?

Comment: the idea is to deserialize a json string into a case class here. I use json4s.parse to extract a Map[String, Any]. I'm willing to use shapeless here, but not any other external library, since I need to control the typeSignatures of these fields

Comment: What do you mean with control the type signature? Also, why reinvent the well, many JSON libraries provide direct support for parsing the JSON into a case class, doesn't **json4** also do that? - Anyways, if you want to do to all by yourself the  yeah use **Shapeless** to derive some `Decoder` instance for any product class.

Comment: Unless you're doing this for learning purposes, I strongly suggest you take Luis' advice and use one of the ready-made json parsing libraries. Circe is a popular one, but there are many other and parsing to a case class is the basic feature they all support.